# When creating in-app purchases, how do I clear purchase data for new tests?

Tags: ios, ios6

I was able to complete a purchase in a sandbox environment, but how do I reset all the data so I can test fresh?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are talking about auto-renewable subscriptions renewing iterations (maximum 5 renews for sandbox), they will refresh after 8 hours (it's not documented anywhere, AFAIK; watch WWDC 2012 video 308).

But if we are talking about non-consumable products - **they won't refresh**. You need to create new test account.

Comment: thanks, yeah I am talking about renewable subscriptions. So essentially, I can test against a fresh set of data every 8 hours or so? :) Am I understanding correctly? :)

Comment: In sense that new subscription will not stuck after first period and will renew for 5 times again.
If you then call 'restoreCompletedTransactions', you will get info about all 12 transactions, and so on.